# TCPDF custom font errors

Tags: php, fonts, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF 6.6.0 to create a document using custom fonts. When I run my program on my local webserver (on my computer), everything works fine. But when I deploy it to a remote webserver, TCPDF doesn't load the custom fonts and the document is blank. My local computer is Windows 10. the remote server is Linux. When I change the program to use just Helvetica fonts, it works correctly. I am getting no error messages.  I have verified that the fonts are on the server.

I used the add_font tool to convert the fonts, which are TrueType Unicode.

Where can I start looking to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I was calling $pdf->AddFont() to add the custom fonts and $pdf->SetFont() to select them. I spent all day throwing stuff at the wall to see what might make a difference. I happened to remove the calls to AddFont(). That did the trick. The font files were already in the tcpdf/fonts folder and only the SetFont() call is apparently needed. Now, I have no idea what the purpose of AddFont() is.  The documentation is poor in describing all of this.